# Interpreting ambiguous agreement

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, ambiguity

> We're proud of our tortilla chips and we hope **you'll agree**.

It may seem trivial but I've seen similar remarks on other products and it just doesn't feel like a valid sentence because I can't determine what they hope I'll agree with them about.

I don't think I'm just missing out on the context as this sentence is preceded by nothing and is only followed by one more:

> Remember, your satisfaction is always guaranteed with [our] brand products.

Am I supposed to share their pride?

Am I supposed to be agreeing that they are proud of their product? If so, is there really a difference between their statement and an example of me saying, "I like pizza and I hope you will agree."

Does anyone know if there is any sort of common characterization of this type of flaw?

Answer (score 7):

My own grammar is not too hot, but the sentence you've quoted is awful. It reads as if they hope you will *agree that they are proud*.

As for naming the error, I'm sure a language expert will manage that more expertly than I can, but as a wild stab I'll suggest it might be a ***dangling modifier***.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Ed's analysis. They want you to *agree that the chips are something to be proud of*: the statement "we are proud of our tortilla chips" implies *because they are good*; and they want you to *agree that the chips are good*.

However, this **[ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)** (the omission of something implicit) fails, because the exact statement that has been left out in ellipsis must be explicit somewhere in the preceding sentence: ellipsis usually doesn't work with implicit statements. We'd be forced to supply the omitted part from the preceding and thus interpret it as *you'll agree that we are proud*.

Any sentence that ends in such a way as to break the grammar of the beginning or vice versa could be considered an ugly **[anacoluthon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacoluthon)**. Or just plain nonsense.

Comment: Of these two options I'd vote for nonsense.

Comment: @EdGuiness: Heh, I am not surprised. I have already up-voted you (I just wanted to mention *anacoluthon*).

Comment: And I upvoted you for it. Aren't we cute.

Comment: @EdGuiness: Yeah, let's hope nobody reads this...

Answer (score 0):

The reason the "advertisers" are proud of their tortilla chips is because they *believe* that their tortilla chips are really good, and they 'hope **you'll agree**'

Comment: How could you know the reason they are proud? They don't say.